# Combine firstname and lastname into fullname

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii2. What I want to achieve is:

- on select to combine `firstName` with `lastName` and get `fullname`
- on insert to seperate them and insert

For this reason, I put my pseudo code below. But when I call `fullname` from view, it returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public $fullname; 
   ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             ...
            [['fullname'], 'safe'],
            ...
        ];
    }
   public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->fullname) {
                $pieces = explode(" ", $this->fullname);
                if (count($pieces) > 1) {
                    $this->firstName = $pieces[0];
                    $this->lastName = $pieces[1];
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function afterFind()
    {

        $this->fullname = "$this->firstName $this->lastName";
        parent::afterFind();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you have a syntax error on the line `[[fullname'], 'safe']` - you're missing an apostrophe

Comment: I don't see you declaring firstName and lastName as public variables (as you did with fullname). Did you?

Comment: @m7o model getting them from database. Fullname is custom variable that will consist of firstName and lastName

Comment: Yes, but you should declare them as public variables when you are using them in two different functions (beforeSave and afterFind). If they are not declared, afterFind does not know them.

Comment: @m7o No, if they are database table columns, they exist as virtual attributes, no need to add them as public properties.

Comment: @arogachev can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: Please add more details/code about "when I call fullname from view, it returns null". And you could use a getter/setter for this.